# Hide custom marker behind elevation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using mapbox and setting multiple custom markers in my map.

How do I hide them (or change their opacity) when they are behind elevations or across long distances??

I've noticed that when I set a default marker instead of a custom one, it already does that by default.
I didn't find anything in the official documentation neither in any other forum that allows me to "turn" that feature on/off.

Basically what I'm doing is

```
const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker(myCustomElement, { anchor: 'bottom' });
```

When I removed `myCustomElement` it defaulted to the mapbox marker and the functionality works flawlessly.

Comment: Relevant github issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/12123

Looks like the default markers have their opacity lowered when behind terrain, but they aren't hidden.  Are you seeing otherwise?  I would think the same opacity setting linked in that issue would apply to custom markers too.  Maybe add a codepen with a custom marker so we can explore?

Comment: Yeah when I mean hide I really meant reducing de opacity sorry if that mislead you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@chriswhong was completely right, the behaviour is the same for custom pins too.
Apperantly the issue in my project was that the .marker class had a `opacity: 1 !important` on it

Only after many hours trying to work this out I found out the problem wasn't in the library.

Also posting a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mapbox-cutom-pin-3rw7tf) for future references.